# Visual Studio UML Class Diagram Generator

Tags: .net, visual-studio, uml

I was wondering if there was a software that would generate UML class diagrams from my project files (C#) in Visual Studio 2008 Professional? Like a plugin of sorts?

I have checked previous posts and did not see anything useful on the first glance.

Edit: I found Class Diagram item! but open to more tips.

Edit: Any ideas regarding how do I go about exporting these diagrams?

Edit: Export diagram as image.

Comment: Can't you use the `ClassDiagram` project item? (project->add new item->general->ClassDiagram)

Comment: well if all else fails alt + print screen is your friend ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about the Visual Studio Class Diagram?

Choose "add New Item" - General category - Class Diagram. Results should be like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [developingfor.net](http://www.developingfor.net/wp-content/uploads/ClassDiagram2.png))</sub>

Comment: your image is missing... could you please upload it again?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the http://modeling.codeplex.com/ add-in.

Answer (score 0):

You can "Copy" and "Paste" the diagram into MSPaint

or you can just print it to the MS Document Image Writer as well.