# UML Class Diagram Generator for PHP and/or Java

Tags: java, php, uml, class-diagram

With reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606615/visual-studio-uml-class-diagram-generator) here - there is a Class Diagram generator for Visual Studio. I've used it and its very useful indeed!

But what I wannna ask - Is there anything like this for PHP and/or Java?

Answer (score 4):

GenMyModel matches, it's an [UML online tool](http://www.genmymodel.com) that generates Java from class diagrams. HTH

Comment: Great tool. The Java generator works fine and it's very easy to use (online).

Comment: You can now write your own UML to Php generator following this tutorial: http://blog.genmymodel.com/build-your-own-php-generator-from-uml-using-acceleo-part-1.html

Answer (score 3):

ArgoUML is nice.  You should also check out [UMLet](http://www.umlet.com/).  UMLet is a a stand-alone UML tool, good for quick class/sequence diagrams.

Comment: From the UMLet site: "UML 2.3 Design Tool .NET, Java, C++, XSD, DDL, PHP, CORBA, Python & more."

Answer (score 2):

This one knows Java and also PHP: http://www.visual-paradigm.com/ And I have got quite good experience with that one. :)

VisualParadigm can help you to generate class diagrams and if you wish, generate also ORM diagrams and make mapping (e.g. in hibernate) between domain classes and database. But you should rather see the official tutorials here: http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/tutorials/

Comment: Is it as easy as the Visual Studio Class Diagram generator?

btw, what's a ORM diagram?

Comment: Yes, it is pretty easy. It is just enought to watch that tutorials I have sent you. ORM is Object Relationship Model - it is step between your domain model and database mapping files. It actually displays domain class diagram as persistent domain classes. I think you could benefit from this page: http://oldresources.visual-paradigm.com/object_relational_mapping/visual_modeling/using_orm_diagram.html

Comment: Wow! That's pretty Kewl! ^_^ Thanks a lot!

I'm downloading the software now... I'll run them in VMWare so "Trial Versions" will never be a problem :D

Answer (score 1):

Visual Paradigm is quite nice, but a bit expensive I think.

A free alternative is ArgoUml. It can generate class diagrams from Java source code (I do not think for php, but I am not sure). It is not quite as good as vp, but it does work and is easy to use.

Netbeans had UML generation integrated up to version 5 or 6, but it was discontinued, so using an older version might work as well.
Eclipse has a plugin called papyrus which also does [code to uml](http://marmoush.com/post/73968328397/papyrus-java-to-uml-reverse-engineering).

For the same functionality for PHP, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393603/php-uml-generator) and see here for a general [overview over UML diagrams](http://software-talk.org/blog/2014/05/comparison-of-free-uml-tools/).

Comment: OK. Thanks. :) 
Do you know something similar for PHP?

Answer (score 0):

[Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/platforms/php_uml.html) and [JetBrains phpStorm](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Working+with+UML+class+diagrams) seem to support UML and PHP.